# Updating div content according to time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need to update my Header `(h1)` according to the current time. For example at `7:45am to 8:00am` 'Current Event' should change to '`Event1`', at `8:00am to 8:15am` it should change to '`Event2`' and so on.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>ShriTeq 2015</title>
 </head>
<body>
<center>
  <img src = "image.png" width = "25%" height = "auto"/>
    <h1 id = "ce" style="font-weight:lighter; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size:70px;">Current Event</h1>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
function headerChange(){
    var d = new Date();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var h = d.getHours();
    if(h == 7 && m>=45){
        $("#ce").html("Event1");
    }else if(h == 8 && m<=15){
        $("#ce").html("Event2");
    }
}
headerChange();
setTimeout(headerChange, 1000);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```js
// All events :
// Event 1 start 2015-10-09 at 00:00:00 to 06:00:00, Event 2 from 06:00:01 to 12:00:00. If out of dates, Default message is shown.
var eventTimes = [
  {
   name: "Event 1",
   from: new Date('2015-10-09T00:00:00').getTime(),
   to: new Date('2015-10-09T06:00:00').getTime()
  },
  {
   name: "Event 2",
   from: new Date('2015-10-09T06:00:01').getTime(),
   to: new Date('2015-10-09T12:00:00').getTime()
  }
  
 ]


 function updateEventName() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var name = "Default message";
  for (var i = 0; i < eventTimes.length; i++) {
   if (now >= eventTimes[i].from && now <= eventTimes[i].to) {
    name = eventTimes[i].name;
    break;
   }
  }
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = name;

 }

// Execute the function every second
setInterval(updateEventName, 1000);

updateEventName();
```

```html
<!--<html>
 <head>
    <title>ShriTeq 2015</title>
 </head>
<body> -->
<center>
  <img alt = 'Missing Img' src = "image.png" width = "25%" height = "auto"/>
    <h1 id = "ce" style="font-weight:lighter; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size:70px;">Current Event</h1>
</center>

<!--
</body>
</html>
-->
```