# Live update of content inside html element according to time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update content inside an html element based on the time of day, I'm doing something similar to this: [Updating div content according to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032266/updating-div-content-according-to-time) but I want the content to update without a page refresh.

code:

```
function schoolPeriod() {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();

    // prepend minutes with 0 if < 10
    if (m < 10) {
      m = "0" + m;
    }

    h = h.toString();
    m = m.toString();

    var t = h + m;

    var periods = [
        "school assembly",
        "first period",
        "second period",
        ];

        var currentPeriod = document.querySelector('.current-period');

        if (t >= 600) {
            currentPeriod.innerHTML = "new school day";
        }  
        else if (t >= 900) {
            currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[0];
        }
        else if (t >= 940) {
            currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[1];
        }
        else if (t >= 1020) {
            currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[2];
        }

    setTimeout(schoolPeriod, 1000);
}
schoolPeriod();
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/grRYoN?editors=1011

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help!

Comment: @nnnnnn that totally worked! Thanks! I'll accept your answer if you post it as one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of your `if/else if/else if/else if` tests.

Why? Lets say `t` is 1020. The current `if` condition of `t >= 600` will be true, so that block will be executed rather than any of the `else if`s. (Even if the `if` were skipped, 1020 is also greater than 900 and greater than 940...) If testing a series of `>=` conditions you need to start by testing the highest possibility. (You may also want to think about adding a final `else` statement for when it is not yet 6:00 am.)

Also, `t = h + m` doesn't do what you expect, because it doesn't allow for single-digit minutes (if the time is, say, 10:03 am then h + m will be 103). Instead of converting the hours and minutes to strings, multiple the hours by 100:

```
var t = h * 100 + m;
```

Note that multiplying by 100 doesn't give you a number of minutes, it just makes it easy for you to do comparisons with `600` for 6am, etc.

(There are other things you could do to make the function shorter and more extensible, but the issues I've covered are the things stopping it working in its current form.)

Comment: > 10:03 am then h + m will be 103

I took care of that by doing if (m < 10) {  m = "0" + m;  }. But looks like you have a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes. Note that I just updated that part of my answer to multiply hours by 100 instead of 60. Not the best if you needed to do further calculations on the time, but to get the number 1020 to mean 10:20am that's what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I'll use that, btw would there be any performance hits if I set the timer to 1000ms?

Comment: It shouldn't be a performance issue, but I don't think you need to update the page every second because your algorithm only tests minute values. So setting the timeout to `60000`ms to update every minute should be fine.

Comment: But if the page loads at 9:20:50s, the timer will be off by 50 seconds right? Not a huge issue though.

Comment: That's true. Assuming the clock is correct on the device where the page is loaded, of course. You could update every 10 seconds instead of every second and nobody would notice the difference...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function schoolPeriod() {
        var date = new Date();
        var h = date.getHours();
        var m = date.getMinutes();

        var t = (h * 60) + m;

        var selectedIndex = 0;

        if (t >= 620) {
            selectedIndex = 3;
        }
        else if (t >= 580) {
            selectedIndex = 2;
        }
        else if (t >= 540) {
            selectedIndex = 1;
        }

        var periods = [
            "new school day",
            "school assembly",
            "first period",
            "second period",
        ];

        document.querySelector('.current-period').innerHTML = periods[selectedIndex];

        setTimeout(schoolPeriod, 1000);
    }

    schoolPeriod();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your if then else statements are wrong. It's always check `(t >= 600)`

Replace this with yours:

```
function schoolPeriod() {
var date = new Date();
var h = date.getHours();
var m = date.getMinutes();

h = h.toString();
m = m.toString();

var t = h + m;

var periods = [
    "school assembly",
    "first period",
    "second period",
    ];

    var currentPeriod = document.querySelector('.current-period');

    if (t >= 600 && t< 900) {
        currentPeriod.innerHTML = "new school day";
    }  
    else if (t >= 900 && t<940) {
        currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[0];
    }
    else if (t >= 940 & t<1020) {
        currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[1];
    }
    else if (t >= 1020) {
        currentPeriod.innerHTML = periods[2];
    }

 setTimeout(schoolPeriod, 1000);
}

// Call the function
schoolPeriod();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, the periods are set in minutes - 360 = 6:00

```js
var periods = [
 ['period 1',360,365],
 ['period 2',365,400],
 ['period 3',400,460],
 ['period 4',460,520]
];
function getPeriod(){
 var period = 'School is closed';
 var minutes = new Date().getHours()*60 + new Date().getMinutes();
 for(var i=0;i<periods.length;i++){
  if(minutes>=periods[i][1] && minutes<periods[i][2]){
   period = periods[i][0];
   break;
  }
 }
 document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = period;
 setTimeout(getPeriod,1000);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="getPeriod();">
<div id="period"></div>
</body>
</html>
```